# UNION ALL - Prevent Combining of Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I tried the following but I ended up with a single column Amount2 containing SUM's from Amount1 too.

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(createdDate) as Year, 
    MONTH(createdDate) AS Month, 
    Sum(GrandTotal) AS Amount1
FROM 
    Quotes
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
GROUP BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)
--ORDER BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    YEAR(createdDate) as Year, 
    MONTH(createdDate) AS Month, 
    Sum(GrandTotal) AS Amount2
FROM 
    Quotes
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
AND orderDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate);
```

However I want to keep both Amount1 and Amount2 columns/amounts.

Actually i want to end up with something like the following:

```
Year | Month | Amount1 | Amount2
---------------------------------
2016    4        120       70
2016    5        300       110
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is just to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT YEAR(createdDate) as Year, 
       MONTH(createdDate) AS Month, 
       Sum(GrandTotal) AS Amount1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN orderDate IS NOT NULL THEN GrandTotal END) as Amount2
FROM Quotes
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
GROUP BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate);
```

If you wanted the value on separate rows (instead of in separate columns), then add a key to the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT YEAR(createdDate) as Year, 
       MONTH(createdDate) AS Month, 
       (CASE WHEN orderDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'valid' ELSE 'null' END) as HasOrderDate,
       Sum(GrandTotal) AS Amount
FROM Quotes
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
GROUP BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate),
          (CASE WHEN orderDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'valid' ELSE 'null' END)
ORDER BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate),
         (CASE WHEN orderDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'valid' ELSE 'null' END);
```

Comment: Nice! I like the first suggestion which you called the simplest method and i totally agree. I should have thought about it earlier. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can't obtaion two columns for Amount1 and Amount2 ..with you the result is composed by the same column

the column alias should be the same (and in the first select only)

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(createdDate) as Year, 
    MONTH(createdDate) AS Month, 
    Sum(GrandTotal) AS Amount1
FROM 
    Quotes
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
GROUP BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)
--ORDER BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    YEAR(createdDate) , 
    MONTH(createdDate), 
    Sum(GrandTotal) 
FROM 
    Quotes
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
AND orderDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate);
```

Or if you want to column you should use a proper JOIN

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(a.createdDate) as Year, 
    MONTH(a.createdDate) AS Month, 
    Sum(a.GrandTotal) AS Amount1,
    Sum(b.GrandTotal) AS Amount2   
FROM  Quotes as a 
INNER JOIN Quotes as b on (YEAR(a.createdDate) as YEAR(b.createdDate) 
                           AND MONTH(a.createdDate) = MONTH(b.createdDate))
WHERE a.createdDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
GROUP BY YEAR(a.createdDate), MONTH(a.createdDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)
```

Comment: Actually i want to end up with something like the following:

Year | Month | Amount1 | Amount2
---------------------------------
2016    4        120       70
2016    5        300       110

Comment: I have update the answer .. hope is what you are looking for